# how much memory would it take to store a reference to an object in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management, pass-by-reference

How much memory would it take to store a reference to an object in C++? Will it take different amount of memories to store a reference to an object compare to store a reference to a specific data type in C++ (like int, double and string)? And how much memory would it take to store a pointer to an object? will it be different amount memory usage compare storing reference to an object?

Comment: The same as a pointer. ***And how much memory would it take to store a pointer to an object?*** Usually 32 bits on 32 bit code and 64 bits on 64 bit code.

Comment: This is fundamentally more than one question, and as such I'm voting to close it on the basis that it's too broad. For more information about what's on topic, see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This is kinda tricky. Normally I'd say, `std::cout << sizeof(myreference);`, but that's not gonna work. Neither will `std::cout << sizeof(char &);` Bit of a bummer, that.

Comment: @user4581301 what are you talking about?

Comment: @MrEricSir The answer is the same to all the questions, so it is only one question.

Answer (score 2):

The storage used by a reference is *unspecified*.  Sometimes it will be none, e.g.:

```
void func()
{
    int a;
    int &b = a;
    // ...
}
```

it is likely that `b` will not consume any storage.

Comment: Compiler will eliminate the reference but if a reference does get stored, it's still cost the size of a pointer.

Comment: @YanZhou my answer is according to the C++ Standard  , you are talking about details of some compilers you used

Comment: Yes, it is unspecified whether a reference requires storage per the standard. What I meant is that when it does require storage...

Answer (score 0):

Pointer and reference are exactly the same to compiler. They all occupy the size of a pointer. use `sizeof(void *)` to get the size.

Comment: Pointers to different types may have different sizes

Comment: @M.M A pointer is a pointer, underlying it's just an integer. I fail to see how can you have different sized pointers.

Comment: Those are implementation details, different implementations can differ (often in response to what hardware is in use).  Segmented architectures had a variety of pointer sizes.

Comment: Well, that is true. I have forgotten old hardware. On x86-64 and other modern architectures I think segmentation has been largely dropped. Besides at C++ level, for any pointer `T *` on any single platform, I think it still has a fixed size in the sense that `sizeof(T *) == sizeof(void *)` will always be true. It is implementation detail that the compiler may say that the actual data is in any segment that can use a smaller pointer.